# People Search Sort by Most match

Tags: people-search

I search for "Matt" and I get Mathew, Matt, Montreal, Mott, McDonald, Marcy, Maly, Hatti"

What?

yes, I am serious

So I added Sort by last name ([How do we add Sort By Last Name on People Search?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55230/how-do-we-add-sort-by-last-name-on-people-search)) which is good. But still does not fix result sets.

so I have 2 issues

1. Can I show less result?
2. Can I show the most match or the closest match on the top (sort ascending)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve 1 by turning off phonetic search.

To do this, we go into Central Administration and navigate to the search application and then “Federated Locations”.

Change the “Query Template” under “Location Information” from

```
{searchTerms}
```

to

```
{searchTerms} AND (FirstName:{searchTerms} OR LastName:{searchTerms})
```

Click OK. It seems this settings takes a little bit before the front end gets it, so if it does not work at first, wait a couple of minute and try again.

Comment: Edited - Thanks WilliamWMY. It worked. First time it did not take the whole syntax because I was using the zoom box. Then I went back and notice the change was gone. I pasted directly into the text area instead of opening the zoom box. Thanks

Comment: If I search for "will" it find will or william or williams in the first name and last name. However, if I search for Goro it should find me gorodetsky, then I do another search for Stan and it found Stanley in the last name, which is good. What is going on?

Comment: my bad. i changed it just (FirstName:{searchTerms} OR LastName:{searchTerms}) and it seems to be doing what i need it do. Thank you William

Answer (score 0):

I believe the feature you are referring to is actually called "Phonetic Search" which is only available in People Search. The behaviour you are experiencing is actually meant to work as such. 
If you don't want it, or in need to fine-tune have a look at this article about commands and details on how it works http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaks/archive/2012/01/30/configuring-phonetic-nickname-search-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to try this method as well. See if this works. Thanks again.